# Problem with Flutter fastlane with flavors

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, fastlane

Has anyone used fastlane with flutter and two flavors? I have a flutter application with two schemes App_A and App_B. I am trying to configure fastlane for configuration App_A.
My project:

- configuration: (Debug-App_A, Debug-App_B, Release-App_A, Release-AppB)
- targets: (App_A, App_B)
- scheme: (App_A, App_B)

List of command I do:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter build ios --flavour App_A`
- `cd ios`
- `fastlane ios beta`

output:

```
[20:01:03]: ▸ ❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App_A/Pods-App_A-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App_A' from project 'Runner')
[20:01:03]: ▸ ❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App_A/Pods-App_A-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App_A' from project 'Runner')
[20:01:03]: ▸ ❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App_A/Pods-App_A-resources-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App_A' from project 'Runner')
[20:01:03]: ▸ ❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-App_A/Pods-App_A-resources-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'App_A' from project 'Runner')
```

Answer (score 0):

After `flutter clean` do the following:

```sh
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod update
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
pod update
pod install
```

Then, run the app to make sure everything is working fine,
and now you can your `lane`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install 
cd ..
flutter build ios
flutter run
```